# How to verify that someone owns a website?

Tags: php, ownership

I'm trying to think of ways to, as securely as possible, verify that a user owns a website that they claim to own.

Here are some ways I've seen:

- Upload an obscurely-named HTML file to the root directory with given contents
- Include a meta tag or other comment somewhere in the home page source
- Send an email to an address `@domainwearetryingtovalidate.tld` with a verification link
- Check a CNAME or TXT record
- Check WHOIS records
- Physically validate by calling or emailing the support line, manually updating records

And here are the problems with those methods, in order:

- Some website configurations may not allow for simply uploading a file to the root
- Poor site design might allow a user of that site to add this meta tag themselves
- Websites which provide email services make this useless; take `gmail.com` for example
- That's too complex for most small website owners to figure out how to do
- Those are public; anyone can claim to be whoever. Not to mention most often inaccurate.
- Huuuuge waste of time

Are there any other ways to verify that a user on your site owns a particular website? Of the methods I listed, which of these are best and worst? I ordered them from best to worst in my own opinion, but I'd like to see what others think as well.

I plan on implementing one or more of these in PHP.

Comment: For an automated solution, you're stuck to what you listed. Other major companies (i.e. Google) use one of the first four options. I'd find it incredibly irregular for a user not to be able to do one of the first four.

Comment: I love how you _actually_ thought so long and hard about this silly requirement, but then when you came to the only viable solution, called it a "huuuuge waste of time". Megalols.

Comment: @Tomalak: If you'd like to work for my site for free and manually email and call contact addresses, you can start work Thursday ;)

Comment: I think that the first problem you have to solve is to decide: what does "owning" a website mean? Being an administrator? Having access to the filesystem? Having a legal ownership right? Having a maintenance duty by way of written or spoken agreement? Paying the hosting bills? Paying the domain bills? Paying the designers?

Comment: @Cyclone: I _am_ working for you for free, by virtue of the fact that I'm completely wasting my time contributing to this question.

Comment: @Tomalak: I'd say that owning a website means having enough access to the site that you could verify you own it using one of the methods I listed.

Comment: @Cyclone: So, if you have a compromised Wordpress installation on the website, and I am a hacker, I "own" your website? I suppose that lends a whole new weight to the term!

Comment: @Tomalak: In a way, yes, they do now own your website. Or rather, have owned it. That's not a problem I'm super concerned with, if the hacker really wants to sign the site they hacked up for my service then they can feel free to go ahead.

Comment: What the the 'owner' actually only merely `pwns` the site? It'd be easy to add your token file to the site

Comment: @Marc B: See my comment directly above yours.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I definitely think

> - Upload an obscurely named html file to the root directory with given contents

is the best way to go. I've actually had to do this once. And I don't think many website configurations prevent you from doing this.

If you're really concerned about this, why not allow all (safe) options?

---

Regarding your comment:

> Yes but with MVC systems (such as codeigniter), it can be a hassle to figure out how to access a physical file which isn't a part of the main system

In these *rare* cases, let those admins go with the CNAME / TXT records or call them :-)

Comment: Right.. that's actually where I had to do it ;-)

Comment: The first two I listed were from google webmaster tools

Comment: @Cyclone, I agree with you that the former one seems more secure than the second one.

Comment: The thing that sucks about this is that you end up with one obscurely-named file per service, cluttering up the root directory. It's not a terrible flaw, but there are cleaner alternatives.

Comment: Hmm.. I think you put the obscurely named file there temporarily during the verification process.

Comment: @aioobe You generally need to keep the verification file in place indefinitely (to maintain a verified status) - websites can change ownership. It could be a security issue if the old owner remained verified (and it wouldn't necessarily be possible for the new owner to remove them).

Comment: @BobbyJack "cluttering up the root directory" - The service implementing the verification process doesn't need to use the root directory. They could, for instance, use a `/.well-known` subdirectory instead. If the service requires a file in the root, then the website could internally rewrite the request elsewhere so nothing needs to be physically stored in the root directory if that is not desirable.

Answer (score 7):

Uploading an obscurely named file is the way to go.

You wrote the drawback is that they may not be allowed to upload a file to the root. Well in that case it means they don't own the website, which is what you're trying to find out.

Comment: Exactly. You don't need "root" access to the server, i.e. outside of the `html` or `www` folder.

Comment: I mean not allowed to in that rewrite rules may make it difficult or complex to upload the file

Comment: @Cyclone, true but I guess it's quite rare to disallow access to a physical HTML file.

Comment: Yes but with MVC systems (such as codeigniter), it can be a hassle to figure out how to access a physical file which isn't a part of the main system

Comment: I think CI still allows access to physical HTML files. But just in case, you could also allow the metatag method, so that your users are not stuck in case there's a problem with their .htaccess file or MVC framework.

Comment: CI does allow access by default given the url scheme of `/index.php/controller/function/param/param`, but it's generally rewritten to remove `/index.php/` and you need to exclude files or folders in your .htaccess manually.

Comment: Yea, it's not entirely unusual that a web platform disallows HTTP access to a file that isn't part of its structure. We have several such systems. It's a robust way to lock down a web service.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using meta tag...

> - Include a meta tag

Comment: Why? (What if the root document doesn't serve a `text/html` response?)

Answer (score 0):

The microformats site is down now as I write this, but the Google cache is available. This is a solution for you:

http://microformats.org/wiki/RelMeAuth

Answer (score -1):

Personally I would go with the automated email option.

Ask the user to input their URL and email address, checking that the domain is the same in both cases. The use the same system as password reset systems use:

- Generate a random hash, partly made up of the current microtime and domain
- Store the hash in a database
- Send the user an email with a verification link, where the 'id' parameter is the hash
- Now the user is verified (delete the row from the database)

For added security, store the time that the hash was generated, and then have it time out after an hour or two.

Comment: This doesn't verify ownership of a website - just that they have access to "an" email account on that domain. The email could be managed by an entirely different service to the website. Also, if I run a service that gives end users an `<email-address>@mydomain.com` - should those users be able to verify ownership of `mydomain.com`?!